# Inf values scipy.stats.truncnorm

Tags: python, scipy

I am using this code to sample from a truncated normal:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
Z = truncnorm.rvs(a = 31.399904/0.822358, b = np.inf, loc = 31.399904, scale = 0.822358)
```

It generates inf values for Z, which mess up with the rest of my code. Would you have an idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a truncnorm supported on `[lower, upper]` use

```
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

For example, if you want a truncated norm supported on `[31.399904, np.inf]`
with mean 32 and std deviation 0.822358, then you would use

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lower, upper = 31.399904, np.inf
mu, sigma = 32, 0.822358
X = stats.truncnorm(
    (lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
N = stats.norm(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
data = X.rvs(10000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
ax[0].hist(data, density=True)
ax[1].hist(N.rvs(10000), density=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The top histogram shows the distribution of a sample from the truncnorm, the lower histogram show the distribution of a sample from a standard normal with the same mean and std deviation.

---

If you also want the mean `mu` to equal the left endpoint of the support, then you would use

```
lower, upper = 31.399904, np.inf
mu, sigma = lower, 0.822358
Z = stats.truncnorm.rvs((lower - mu) / sigma, (upper - mu) / sigma, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
```

which is equivalent to

```
Z = stats.truncnorm.rvs(0, np.inf, loc=31.399904, scale=0.822358)
```

For example,

```
In [47]: np.random.seed(1234)
In [49]: stats.truncnorm.rvs(0, np.inf, loc=31.399904, scale=0.822358)
Out[49]: 31.599232630594255
```

---

The problem with

```
Z = truncnorm.rvs(a = 31.399904/0.822358, b = np.inf, loc = 31.399904, scale = 0.822358)
```

is that the mean is at loc=31.3999904, but the left endpoint is around 38.2:

```
In [51]: a = 31.399904/0.822358; a
Out[51]: 38.18276711602489
```

The most likely value of a truncnorm should be at its mean, but the mean falls outside of the support, `[38.2, np.inf]`. This contradiction leads to the bizarre behavior.